# why object ref1 is ready for GC after Console.WriteLine (ref1)?

Tags: c#, heap-memory, stack-memory

I started reading of c# 5.0 in a Nutshell
and now I am on Stack and Heap chapter
There is example of how GC works with heap objects:

```
StringBuilder ref1 = new StringBuilder ("object1");
Console.WriteLine (ref1);
// The StringBuilder referenced by ref1 is now eligible for GC.
```

So author saying that ref1 object is ready for GC after Console.WriteLine, but what if  I want to use ref1 object later in my program?

Comment: Then it would not be eligible for GC.

Comment: Presumably because it is either 1) the last line of the program and/or the last use of `ref1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you're using the reference to an object it will not be eligible for collection. The point of the example is to show that since `ref1` is no longer accessed by the code, the object could be collected at any point after this.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is aware of that there is no links to ref1, so it marks it as unused. If you would have another use of ref1 than compiler would know that and keep it alive. 
J. Richter has a nice book: ".NET CLR via C#". He does explain a lot in the book

Comment: Yes,that what I though at the beginning, but just decided to check if it's something new that I don't know yet. Thanks